# Чего не может C# в отличие от Scheme для работы с ИИ?

Tags: c#, lisp, метапрограммирование, scheme, самомодификация

Почему для работ в области искусственного интеллекта часто выбирают какой-нибудь из диалектов Лиспа или Пролог, что в них такого, чего нельзя сделать на C#? Интересуют именно сравнение **возможностей** (что можно сделать в одном языке программирования, но невозможно или проблематично в другом) языка, а не готовых алгоритмов/методов или их количества.

**upd**: Нашел проект [IronScheme](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/), зеркало [Github](https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme)

> IronScheme implements over 99% of the R6RS specification and specified behavior.

[пример работы из C#](http://cryks.hateblo.jp/entry/20120417/1334660328), [документация](http://ironscheme.net/doc)

Comment: На ответ не тянет (про C# ничего).

В нагугленной ссылке [Почему Lisp?](http://lisper.ru/pcl/introduction-why-lisp) мне понравилась фраза

>В качестве девиза для Common Lisp лучше всего подходит похожее на дзенский коан описание "программируемый язык программирования".

Видимо, подобное свойство языка  должно быть близко разработчикам ИИ. По сути (если отбросить прикладные аспекты) интеллект - это способность к размышлениям, которые порождают размышления, увеличивают уровень познания (конечно, отталкиваясь от наблюдаемых фактов).

Comment: >что в них такого, чего нельзя сделать на C#

у C# проблемы с автоматическим выводом типов в общем и для делегатов `Func` и `Action` в частности - это единственное, что мне не нравится в нём

Comment: А причём тут Lisp и Scheme с их динамической типизацией?

Comment: В C# нет метапрограммирования времени компиляции. В языках семейства LISP оно есть. (Синтаксические макро)

Comment: В C# нет анафорических лямбд и пандоричеких макросов.

Comment: @typemoon:  ответ полный есть тут

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вполне законно вопрос поставить шире: сравнение возможностей процедурного, функционального и логического программирования. Вопрос очень широкий и требует как минимум хорошей академической статьи.

В принципе, возможности большинства языков всех этих групп достаточно близки. Вопрос только в простоте и легкости реализации тех или иных задач. Думаю, все, что можно сделать на Лиспе или Прологе, вполне возможно реализовать и на C#. Только там, где на этих языках та или иная операция будет занимать пару строчек, на процедурном языке может занять пару десятков.

Comment: Есть такая гипотеза Тьюринга (недоказуемая). Упрощенно она гласит - любой алгоритм можно запрограммировать на машине Тьюринга. Следствие - если на некотором языке можно эмулировать машину Тьюринга, то на нем можно запрограммировать любой алгоритм. Но я  бы хотел посмотреть как на с# реализовать унификацию термов

Comment: @mikillskeg C# -- язык с процедурными, объедко-ориентированными и функциональными средствами. Вот логическое программирование (если я не путаю) тут мимо кассы.

Comment: @alexlz, просто в вопросе был упомянут Пролог.

Comment: Согласен по сути, но не согласен с формулировкой. Это слишком общий ответ на вполне конкретный вопрос. Из вашего ответа непонятно, зачем вообще тогда существуют разные языки, ни одного примера вы не привели.

Comment: @renegator пожалуйста, на C#: http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @skegg "Вопрос очень широкий и требует как минимум хорошей академической статьи.", ну что же, появилась целая книга "Парадигма программирования. Учебное пособие Городняя Л." 
Курс лекций посвящен проблеме анализа, сравнения и определения парадигм программирования ". Добавьте пожалуйста в ответ.

Answer (score 8):

[Scheme - изящный и простой язык](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/racket/), к тому-же близость синтаксиса к соответствующему [AST Tree](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) позволяет программисту интуитивно генерировать [необходимые языки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA) с помощью *макросов*. Вообще, для Scheme естественно, что [код - это данные](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity). Это полезно для разработчиков [всевозможного](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) [матана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC), в тч специфичного для AI (обработка и генерация графов - сильное место любого Lisp), но также и [интернет-магазинов...](http://www.nestor.minsk.by/sr/2003/07/30710.html).

Есть в *Scheme* [принципиально отсутствующие](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685806/c-sharp-first-class-continuation-via-c-interop-or-some-other-way) в *C#* сущности, например: *[продолжения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))* (*[Continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)*), как объекты первого класса. Это фактически значит, что состояние всей программы можно сохранять и восстанавливать на уровне языка.

Scheme - мультипарадигменный язык, его философия не навязывает ООП, равно как чисто-функциональное или реактивное программирование. Экосистема Scheme поддерживает развитые средства для любых, в т.ч. и эксперементальных методик.

Хотя не существует единого репозитария Scheme-кода и стандарта модульности, зато развита теория и добрая традиция переиспользования функций, построенных (возможно) в разных стилях. Есть и база качественного кода на Scheme. Скажем, их даже несколько.

[REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) - традиционный для LISP способ коммуникации с интерпретатором, "выращивания" окружений. Изменения вносятся в непрерывно работающую программу - подобным образом математики работают с [Maxima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_%28software%29) и её аналогами.  Для некоторых современных языков, того-же *С#*, совершенно необходимо специальное IDE. Однако есть и мнение, что [IDE в целом усложняет процесс разработки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610869/clojure-development-ide-or-repl), во всяком случае - итеративный процесс разработки очевидно помогает разгрузить оперативную память программиста.

Существуют компиляторы и интерпретаторы *Scheme* для любой архитектуры - ARM, Webkit/ECMAScript, .NET, Java... Благодаря простоте, Scheme - в мире, один из самых портированых языков. С недавних пор, он выбран [стандартным языком расширения GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Guile), и на этой платформе построен [дистрибутив GUIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/) с демоном инициализации [Shepherd](https://www.gnu.org/software/shepherd/) (замена init и systemd).

Comment: «...первая версия Javascript, как и **большинства современных языков**, была написана на Scheme». А можно поподробнее? C? C++? C#? Java? Go? Rust? Ruby? Python? Swift?

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы перечислили столько *несовременных* языков, однако согласен - это очень спорное утверждение, из ответа его стоит убрать, чтобы не разводить холивар. Однако, в природе есть такая информация о многих языках, например Haskell. А  Ruby его создатель (Matz) вообще называет Matz-lisp, хотя первая версия его была написана на C. Но автор на момент проектирования очевидно думал на Scheme или, как минимум в AST-tree. Тут надо различать то, на чём написан интерпретатор фактически из соображений производительности (как правило C) и то, на чём создавался *язык*

Comment: Ну, а что _вы_ считаете современными языками? Может быть, C вышел из моды, но C++ активно развивается, а C# уж точно впереди планеты всей.

Comment: ну не C и C++ Java - определённо

Comment: Окей, понял. Спасибо!

Comment: забавно кстати, что *C*  - более актуален чем громоздкий *C++* , замен которому множество.  *C* остался незаменим и используется  в самом большом проекте современности - ядре Linux

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31843/discussion-between-11111000000-and-vladd).

Comment: @11111000000 _"в самом большом проекте современности - ядре Linux"_ -- в каких единицах измерения? если в SLOC, то есть проекты  крупнее. http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/million-lines-of-code/

Comment: @Stack: это не относится к теме, но очевидно по числу задействованных  "человеко-часов", буквально, программистов

Answer (score 4):

Есть множество языков программирования. Вот для алгоритмов или ИИ нужна спец. подготовка. А специалистов таких не много. Теперь выберите из этого числа людей тех, кто на профессиональном уровне знает тот же С#. Вот и получается что тем, кто занимается ИИ, проще написать (())О() в пару строк - и все готово. Тут тебе и строгой типизации нет, и ООП учить (почти) не надо. А вообще была бы возможность, выучил бы F#. У меня даже книга есть по нем. Но язык мне действительно показался сложноватым.

Comment: по F# есть хорошая книга **Functional Programming for the Real World**, всё изложение построено по принципу сравнения этого языка с C#

Comment: "Но язык мне действительно показался сложноватым." Сложностей в нем не так уж и много -- бардачность от OCaml и ООП от .NET

Разве что обычные проблемы изучения функционального программирования для имеющих опыт императивного. Но тут уж ничего не поделаешь...

Comment: _"язык мне действительно показался сложноватым"_ -- после c# - согласен. код очень сжатый, иногда сильно `закрученный`. и возможностей больше, например active pattern

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, то, что сама идеология Лисп, в отличие от идеологии С#, более подходит для написания самомодифицирующегося кода - кода, анализирующего и модифицирующего самого себя.

То есть Лисп свой собственный исходник может обрабатывать как данные.